# Error in implementing a Red black Tree using a sentinel object, in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, red-black-tree, clrs

So, I am trying to implement insertion for a red black tree, using sentinels as described in the "Introduction to Algorithms".

I've created a Generic class for a red black node, which has type parameter as its data attribute and the other attributes: parent(node type), leftchild(node type), rightchild(node type) and a color(enum type having red and black values).

Red-Back Node Class:-

```
public class RedBlackTreeNode<T extends Comparable<T>> {

enum color{
    RED,
    BLACK
}

private T data;
private color color;
private RedBlackTreeNode<T> leftChild;
private RedBlackTreeNode<T> rightChild;
private RedBlackTreeNode<T> parent;


public RedBlackTreeNode(T data) {
    this.data = data;
    leftChild = null;
    rightChild = null;
    parent = null;
    color = null;
}


public T getData() {
    return data;
}
public void setData(T data) {
    this.data = data;
}
public color getColor() {
    return color;
}
public void setColor(color color) {
    this.color = color;
}
public RedBlackTreeNode<T> getLeftChild() {
    return leftChild;
}
public void setLeftChild(RedBlackTreeNode<T> leftChild) {
    this.leftChild = leftChild;
}
public RedBlackTreeNode<T> getRightChild() {
    return rightChild;
}
public void setRightChild(RedBlackTreeNode<T> rightChild) {
    this.rightChild = rightChild;
}
public RedBlackTreeNode<T> getParent() {
    return parent;
}
public void setParent(RedBlackTreeNode<T> parent) {
    this.parent = parent;
}
```

}

Red Black Tree Class:

```
import redBlackTree.RedBlackTreeNode.color;

public class RedBlackTree<T extends Comparable<T>> {

    private RedBlackTreeNode<T> sentinel

;
    private RedBlackTreeNode<T> root;

    public RedBlackTree() {
        sentinel = new RedBlackTreeNode<>(null);
        sentinel.setColor(color.BLACK);
        root = null;
    }

    public void redBlackInsert(RedBlackTreeNode<T> z) {

        RedBlackTreeNode<T> y, x;
        int temp;

        y = sentinel;
        x = this.root;

        //Getting NullPointerException in the below while loop condition
        while ((x.getData()) != null) {
            y = x;

            temp = z.getData().compareTo(x.getData());
            if (temp < 0) {
                x = x.getLeftChild();
            } else {
                x = x.getRightChild();
                System.out.println("Right child of X: " + x);
                System.out.println("Sentinel: " + x);
            }
        }

        z.setParent(y);

        if (y.getData() != null) {
            temp = z.getData().compareTo(y.getData());
            if (temp < 0) {
                y.setLeftChild(z);
            } else {
                y.setRightChild(z);
            }
        } else {
            root = z;
        }
        z.setLeftChild(sentinel);
        z.setRightChild(sentinel);
        z.setColor(color.RED);

        redBlackInsertFix(z);
        System.out.println("First node inserted");

    }

    private void redBlackInsertFix(RedBlackTreeNode<T> z) {
        while (z.getParent().getColor() == color.RED) {
            if (z.getParent() == z.getParent().getParent().getLeftChild()) {
                RedBlackTreeNode<T> y;
                y = z.getParent().getParent().getRightChild();
                if (y.getColor() == color.RED) {
                    z.getParent().setColor(color.BLACK);
                    y.setColor(color.BLACK);
                    z.getParent().getParent().setColor(color.RED);
                    z = z.getParent().getParent();
                } else if (z == z.getParent().getRightChild()) {
                    z = z.getParent();
                    leftRotate(z);
                }
                z.getParent().setColor(color.BLACK);
                z.getParent().getParent().setColor(color.RED);
                rightRotate(z.getParent().getParent());
            } else {
                RedBlackTreeNode<T> y;
                y = z.getParent().getParent().getLeftChild();
                if (y.getColor() == color.RED) {
                    z.getParent().setColor(color.BLACK);
                    y.setColor(color.BLACK);
                    z.getParent().getParent().setColor(color.RED);
                    z = z.getParent().getParent();
                } else if (z == z.getParent().getLeftChild()) {
                    z = z.getParent();
                    rightRotate(z);
                }
                z.getParent().setColor(color.BLACK);
                z.getParent().getParent().setColor(color.RED);
                leftRotate(z.getParent().getParent());
            }
        }
        root.setColor(color.BLACK);

    }

    private void rightRotate(RedBlackTreeNode<T> y) {

        RedBlackTreeNode<T> x;
        x = y.getLeftChild();
        y.setLeftChild(x.getRightChild());
        if (x.getRightChild() != sentinel) {
            x.getRightChild().setParent(y);
        }
        x.setParent(y.getParent());
        if (y.getParent() == sentinel) {
            root = x;
        } else if (y == y.getParent().getLeftChild()) {
            y.getParent().setLeftChild(x);
        } else {
            y.getParent().setRightChild(x);
        }
        x.setRightChild(y);
        y.setParent(x);
    }

    private void leftRotate(RedBlackTreeNode<T> x) {

        RedBlackTreeNode<T> y;
        y = x.getRightChild();
        x.setRightChild(y.getLeftChild());
        if (y.getLeftChild() != sentinel) {
            y.getLeftChild().setParent(x);
        }
        y.setParent(x.getParent());
        if (x.getParent() == sentinel) {
            root = y;
        } else if (x == x.getParent().getLeftChild()) {
            x.getParent().setLeftChild(y);
        } else {
            x.getParent().setRightChild(y);
        }
        y.setLeftChild(x);
        x.setParent(y);
    }

    public void inOrderTraversal(RedBlackTreeNode<T> x) {

        if (x.getData() != sentinel.getData()) {
            inOrderTraversal(x.getLeftChild());
            System.out.println(x.getData());
            inOrderTraversal(x.getRightChild());
        }
    }

    public RedBlackTreeNode<T> getRoot() {
        return root;
    }
}
```

And here is the class having the main method:

```
public class RedBlackTreeDriver {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        RedBlackTreeNode<Integer> one = new RedBlackTreeNode<>(50);
        RedBlackTreeNode<Integer> two = new RedBlackTreeNode<>(55);
        RedBlackTreeNode<Integer> three = new RedBlackTreeNode<>(48);
        
        RedBlackTree<Integer> rbt = new RedBlackTree<>();
        
        //System.out.println(rbt.getRoot());
        
        //NullPointerException
        rbt.redBlackInsert(one);
        
        System.out.println("ROOT: "+ rbt.getRoot());
        
        rbt.redBlackInsert(two); 
        rbt.redBlackInsert(three);
    
        System.out.println(rbt.getRoot());
        
        rbt.inOrderTraversal(rbt.getRoot());
    }

}
```

I am trying to add a sentinel node(having the data attribute set as "null") after inserting every node with value. So, after adding the first node, I should be able to go down the tree(looking for sentinel) and add the new node to the parent of the sentinel.

I'm getting a null pointer exception in the Red Black Tree class.
So far,I've tried almost everything I know.
Can someone guide me through this?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so after thinking a bit, I got to this point where I just made sure that for the first time, when we are inserting a node, it should not check for the while loop condition.
And here it is, the change in the Red Black Tree Class:

```
package redBlackTree;

import redBlackTree.RedBlackTreeNode.color;

public class RedBlackTree<T extends Comparable<T>> {

    private RedBlackTreeNode<T> sentinel;
    private RedBlackTreeNode<T> root;

    public RedBlackTree() {
        sentinel = new RedBlackTreeNode<>(null);
        sentinel.setColor(color.BLACK);
        root = null;
    }

    public void redBlackInsert(RedBlackTreeNode<T> z) {

        RedBlackTreeNode<T> y, x;
        int temp;

        y = sentinel;
        x = this.root;

        System.out.println(x);

        // Getting NullPointerException in the below while loop condition
        if (x != null) {
            while (x.getData() != null) {
                y = x;

                temp = z.getData().compareTo(x.getData());
                if (temp < 0) {
                    x = x.getLeftChild();
                } else {
                    x = x.getRightChild();
                    System.out.println("Right child of X: " + x);
                    System.out.println("Sentinel: " + sentinel);
                }
            }
        }
        z.setParent(y);

        if (y.getData() != null) {
            temp = z.getData().compareTo(y.getData());
            if (temp < 0) {
                y.setLeftChild(z);
            } else {
                y.setRightChild(z);
            }
        } else {
            root = z;
        }
        z.setLeftChild(sentinel);
        z.setRightChild(sentinel);
        z.setColor(color.RED);

        redBlackInsertFix(z);
        System.out.println("First node inserted");

    }

    private void redBlackInsertFix(RedBlackTreeNode<T> z) {
        while (z.getParent().getColor() == color.RED) {
            if (z.getParent() == z.getParent().getParent().getLeftChild()) {
                RedBlackTreeNode<T> y;
                y = z.getParent().getParent().getRightChild();
                if (y.getColor() == color.RED) {
                    z.getParent().setColor(color.BLACK);
                    y.setColor(color.BLACK);
                    z.getParent().getParent().setColor(color.RED);
                    z = z.getParent().getParent();
                } else if (z == z.getParent().getRightChild()) {
                    z = z.getParent();
                    leftRotate(z);
                }
                z.getParent().setColor(color.BLACK);
                z.getParent().getParent().setColor(color.RED);
                rightRotate(z.getParent().getParent());
            } else {
                RedBlackTreeNode<T> y;
                y = z.getParent().getParent().getLeftChild();
                if (y.getColor() == color.RED) {
                    z.getParent().setColor(color.BLACK);
                    y.setColor(color.BLACK);
                    z.getParent().getParent().setColor(color.RED);
                    z = z.getParent().getParent();
                } else if (z == z.getParent().getLeftChild()) {
                    z = z.getParent();
                    rightRotate(z);
                }
                z.getParent().setColor(color.BLACK);
                z.getParent().getParent().setColor(color.RED);
                leftRotate(z.getParent().getParent());
            }
        }
        root.setColor(color.BLACK);

    }

    private void rightRotate(RedBlackTreeNode<T> y) {

        RedBlackTreeNode<T> x;
        x = y.getLeftChild();
        y.setLeftChild(x.getRightChild());
        if (x.getRightChild() != sentinel) {
            x.getRightChild().setParent(y);
        }
        x.setParent(y.getParent());
        if (y.getParent() == sentinel) {
            root = x;
        } else if (y == y.getParent().getLeftChild()) {
            y.getParent().setLeftChild(x);
        } else {
            y.getParent().setRightChild(x);
        }
        x.setRightChild(y);
        y.setParent(x);
    }

    private void leftRotate(RedBlackTreeNode<T> x) {

        RedBlackTreeNode<T> y;
        y = x.getRightChild();
        x.setRightChild(y.getLeftChild());
        if (y.getLeftChild() != sentinel) {
            y.getLeftChild().setParent(x);
        }
        y.setParent(x.getParent());
        if (x.getParent() == sentinel) {
            root = y;
        } else if (x == x.getParent().getLeftChild()) {
            x.getParent().setLeftChild(y);
        } else {
            x.getParent().setRightChild(y);
        }
        y.setLeftChild(x);
        x.setParent(y);
    }

    public void inOrderTraversal(RedBlackTreeNode<T> x) {

        if (x.getData() != sentinel.getData()) {
            inOrderTraversal(x.getLeftChild());
            System.out.println(x.getData());
            inOrderTraversal(x.getRightChild());
        }
    }

    public RedBlackTreeNode<T> getRoot() {
        return root;
    }
}
```

I hope this was not a very naive question to ask.